# how to search with stristr

Tags: php, array-filter

i have 2 arrays

```
$filtered_url_list= array("www.salmat.", "www.webcentral.");
```

and

```
 $files = array("http://www.salmat.", "http://www.webcentral.", "http://abc.");
```

i want to search for elements of `$filtered_url_list` in array `$files`. If part of the string of `$files`' elements match then respective `$files`' string needs to be `echo`ed

my code looks like this

```
foreach($filtered_url_list as $check_val)
{
  $found=FALSE;
  foreach($files as $file_val)
  {
    if(stristr($check_val,$file_val)!==FALSE)
    {
        $found=TRUE;
    }
  }
  if(!$found)
  {
    echo $file_val,"\n";
  }
```

}
Example :
 `www.salmat. is present in http://www.salmat. if this is true then echo http://www.salmat.`
My echo statement is incorrect. But i m not getting how to make it correct

Please suggest

Thankyou

Comment: Is `$contents` the same as `$files`?

Comment: yep they are same i just edited the qs

Answer (score 1):

Put the `echo` in the `foreach`. Also, the order of the arguments for the `stristr` function is wrong.

```
foreach($filtered_url_list as $check_val)
{
  $found=FALSE;
  foreach($files as $file_val)
  {
    if(stristr($file_val,$check_val)!==FALSE)
    {
      $found=TRUE;
      echo $file_val,"\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not echo any thing

Comment: @MNCD Have you changed the order of the arguments of the `stristr` function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
foreach($filtered_url_list as $check_val)
{
  if(in_array ($check_val ,$contents))
  {
    //$chcekc_val values is present in $contents array. 
  }
 }
```

For reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: This funct checks for perfect string hence not useful

Answer (score -1):

Use strcmp instead

```
    if(strcmp($check_val,$file_val) ==0)
```

Comment: i want to just compare string in a to a string

Comment: eg `www.salmat.` is present in `http://www.salmat.` if this is true then echo `http://www.salmat.`

Comment: The answer that was upvoted should be the correct answer you are looking for in that case.